# Chemformula giving Missing number, treated as zero error

Tags: errors, miktex, texstudio, chemformula

I've recently installed TeXstudio and MiKteX on a new Windows 11 machine and have been trying to compile some of my old .tex files which uses chemformula:

```
  \documentclass[answers, 12pt]{exam}
    \usepackage{chemformula}
    \begin{document}
    \ch{Na2SO4}
    \end{document}
```

Error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \ch{Na2SO4}
```

I didn't get this error on my old machine or on overleaf. Just wondering what's causing this problem and if there's any way to fix it.

**Log file** https://pastebin.com/1M8jx25D

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me. Show the complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Log file here: https://pastebin.com/1M8jx25D

Comment: you have a local chemformula.sty in your document folder.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the local chemformula.sty fixed it